# How to use Facebook connect to login in to my database?

Tags: facebook

I have a mysql membership database run by a Perl script. Account creation or login requires an email address and password. The Perl script then sets cookies (password cookie has encrypted value) which allow users to create, own and modify records. A members table contains user information. I've gone through the FacebookConnect information as well as the forum. Maybe I cannot see the forest for the trees, or maybe this is not possible. In order to use FacebookConnect for logins/account creation, I need to be able to send the user email and password to the the Perl script so that the proper cookies are set. If it were an http it would look like this:

http://domain.com/cgi-bin/perlscript.pl?_cgifunction=login&email=ddd@somedomain.com&password=somepassword.

Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but I would like to point out that authentication shouldn't be done by visiting a URL in the browser. The login information would be stored plain-text in the history and it has potential to be read (HTTP-referrer, javascript).

Comment: First get all data from facebook and stored into some array then you create manualll program to check into datase.. here is more information to get more user info from facebook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718722/how-i-can-get-user-email-and-name-with-facebook-connect-new-platform/10766525#10766525

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to do isn't really possible in the way that you're describing it.

Facebook Connect basically provides you with a single piece of information:  whether your visitor is logged in to their Facebook account or not.  If they are, you can get their Facebook ID, if not, you can show them a button (or whatever) and ask them to log into Facebook.

Generally a good approach when using Facebook Connect as an authentication method for your site is to have an internal id for the user's member account, and store a user's Facebook ID alongside that.  When a user comes to your site, and they are already logged in to Facebook, you just use their Facebook ID to retrieve the local account.  Otherwise you show them your login form to log in locally, and/or a Facebook login button.

The problem you're running into here is that you cannot get someone's email address from Facebook, as it is purposely hidden to protect privacy.  If your membership scripts provide only the email/password log-in method, then what you need to do is modify these scripts to create the authentication cookie when given a properly authenticated Facebook ID.

Essentially you'll have two login functions... one for a Facebook login, and one for a regular login.  Either function should properly created the local authentication cookie.