# email id of user from new facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have worked earlier on facebook API. I successfully used it and fetched all friend lists with their email ids. I was also able to get user email id who logged in through facebook API.

Now in gap of 7-8 months I found that faceAPI development section has been changed . New one is something different.

And now I am facing problem to get email id after user login at facebook.Yet all other details are coming like user name .user id and location except email id.

Old script is also not working with me. Could you help me to get email id of user who get login by facebook at my website.

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I have read this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072819/how-to-get-the-user-email-address-in-facebook-facebook-connect-or-graph-api                                                                          My problem is somewhat similar to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No one will do your homework (upgrade the code for you)
2. Read the most current [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)
3. Accessing users e-mails require a special permission [`email`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
4. Users may choose **not** sharing their direct e-mail with you
5. You didn't say what technology you are using, but you can check the PHP-SDK [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) page to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Access Method:

Log into Facebook under your name.  If you need an "Access Token", Click on the Extended Permissions and click the "read_friendlist" check box to get your Access Token and then 
submit your query.  You may need to "Allow" access, so just follow the prompts given.
Voila!  You now have the usernames for everyone on your Friends List. The "username" parameter in the query will give you the contact email "message to that person" and you append @facebook.com and send them a message.  Very simple.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20username%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20ORDER%20BY%20name

I had been using the import function in Yahoo Mail but now it has been limited to the first 50 names on your friends list.  Where I work, they have over 6,000 friends between the two pages.  This is a very simple solution to my problem.  And now I can write a very small PHP sendmail program and send EVERYONE on the friends list an email message that goes directly to their messages.  No more viewing page sources or manually doing this.
I can create a special email list on IFanz that will handle all dups, even if I repeat this process on a monthly basis to acquire new emails.

-SAB