# How to get the email address of a Facebook user using the graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email) over and over, and yet it doesn't make sense to me.

What I am trying to do is acquire a Facebook user's email address so that I can store it in a string and compare to see if it matches the emails of existing users in my MySQL database. I only need to to do this when the user first grants access rights to the app.

In the "Authenticated Referrals" section of my app developer interface, I have set "User & Friend Permissions" to include "email".

Within the "canvas" area of my site, I have this code:

```
include('facebook/base_facebook.php');
include('facebook/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    'secret' => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user)
{
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

If I var_dup() $user, I can see the user id (though not much else) which seems to be correct, so I believe I'm connecting to the right place on Facebook.

But then there was [this suggested line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611682/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-users-email#comment3792810_3611781), which implies that it returns an email address, but when I echo it out to see what it looks like, it doesn't return an email address:

```
echo "<br/>" . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));
```

I kind of thought it wouldn't, as it doesn't look quite right to me, but on the other hand, I just have no idea what else to do with it or where to put it.

And then I also came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072819/how-to-get-the-user-email-address-in-facebook-facebook-connect-or-graph-api), which has code mixed in with the HTML in a way that baffles me even further.

Assuming that my user has granted permission for my app to see their email, isn't there a simple way of getting at it? Something an inexperienced programmer like myself can grasp?

Comment: How are you implementing facebook login? Offical php sdk and javascript sdk? And yeah now it should be scope not req_perms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using outdated method. You can use the code below to retrieve the email.

You can find more information about Facebook Connect from : http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

```
$app_id     = "xxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$site_url   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

include_once "src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => $app_id,
    'secret'    => $app_secret,
    ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        $user = NULL;
    }
}

if($user){
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'email',
        'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
        ));
}

if($user){
    Echo "Email : " . $user_profile['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in comments you should replace `req_perms` with `scope` since it is the name for field indicating which `permissions` to be granted by users.

Once `email` permission is granted (do you see it's asked in the Auth Dialog?) you'll be able to get `email` field via Graph API. You can also retrieve only required fields in results by specifying 'em in the `fields` parameter:

```
$facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email'));
```

**BTW**, Please not that both posts you refer to are old (2010), way many things changed in the platform. Be sure to read updated documentation on [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Finally I found how to get user data! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a Facebook username with the e-mail address. For example, my username is "umair.hamid.79" on Facebook. It will be "umair.hamid.79@facebook.com".