# How to get email of a face book account

Tags: facebook

I have an android application which need the email address of the face book logged in candidate.

My application works as follows

the user can log in to my application using his face book account. After logged in he can select some items and clicks on OK button. When the user clicks the button ok we need to send an email to his "email address" telling that the details of the items he selected.

I am able to get the first_name and Last_name values but i also need the email address.

can any one tell me how to get the email.

Comment: Have a look, i have briefed out the steps, to get user information using facebook connect and facebook php sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718722/how-i-can-get-user-email-and-name-with-facebook-connect-new-platform/10766525#10766525

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Facebook extended permissions for that. Specifically you need the `email` extended permission.

[Here's the link to the documentation where you can take a look at all Facebook's permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) you can use in its API.

When you [authenticate](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), just make sure scope contains `email` like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream
```